# Django: access the string value in a forms.CharField WITHIN the ModelForm class

Tags: django, forms

Within the Form class below, I let the user enter a street name, a number and a zipcode.

```
class MeldingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    street = forms.CharField(max_length=256, help_text="Street: ")
    number = forms.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Number: ")
    zip = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((34000, 'TownA'), (34001, 'TownB'),
                                     (34010, 'TownC'), (34012, 'TownD')))
```

I want to automatically extract the coordinates by using the values (strings) of these three fields.
I defined a method get_closest_coords() which takes these 3 strings as arguments (and works very well in other occasions) and tried this WITHIN the class definition so I can assign the value to the coordinate variables.

```
    lat, lng = get_closest_coords(street.__str__(), number.__str__())

    coord_lat = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=lat)
```

I have tried various ways to acces the string value of these fields, but none has worked for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it myself in the meantime.
It's actually pretty simple. My question basically shows that I didn't fully grasp the principles Django works with.

You cannot set new values for an attribute in the class definition (except defaults). The appropriate place to do it is in the views.py file of your app (I think). Below is how I solved it:

```
class MeldingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    street = forms.CharField(max_length=256, help_text="Street: ")
    number = forms.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="Number: ")
    zip = forms.CharField(max_length=4, initial='34000')
```

In the views.py file of the app, in the definition of the add_Melding function, I added the following section (after checking validity of form entries etc...)

```
def add_Melding(request):
    melder = request.user
    form = MeldingForm(request.POST)
    melding = form.save(commit=False)
    melding.melder = melder
    melding.coord_lng, melding.coord_lat = get_closest_coords(melding.street, melding.number, melding.zip)
    melding.save()
```

So the clue is to set the form entries first, without committing them (commit = false), then assign the new values (in this case the melder and the coordinates) and then save the form properly.
Hope this helps! Feel free to comment if you have better suggestions!